# Ubuntu unavaliable install redis-stack-server

Tags: redis

according to https://redis.io/docs/stack/get-started/install/linux/, I am trying to install redis-stack on my ubuntu machine with ppa:

```
curl -fsSL https://packages.redis.io/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/redis-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/redis-archive-keyring.gpg] https://packages.redis.io/deb $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install redis-stack-server
```

However with error:

```
E: Unable to locate package redis-stack-server
```

So, I am trying to download linux binary file to machine, still error:

```
$ ./bin/redis-stack-server

Starting redis-stack-server, database path ./var/db/redis-stack
./bin/redis-server: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```